How Many Lists Can Be Created by Moving One Element to Another Position?
How many distinct lists can be created by removing an element from one position of a given list of length n and then inserting it into another position (concerns shifting all elements)? For example, from (1, 2, 3, 4) we can create:
shifting 4: (4, 1, 2, 3) (1, 4, 2, 3) (1, 2, 4, 3) (1, 2, 3, 4)
shifting 3: (3, 1, 2, 4) (1, 3, 2, 4) (1, 2, 3, 4) (1, 2, 4, 3)
shifting 2: (2, 1, 3, 4) (1, 2, 3, 4) (1, 3, 2, 4) (1, 3, 4, 2)
shifting 1: (1, 2, 3, 4) (2, 1, 3, 4) (2, 3, 1, 4) (2, 3, 4, 1)
A total of 9 valid lists. The answer is $(n - 1)^2$, but I don't understand how to derive this.
More specifically, it's about generating the neighborhood of list A by moving each element from its original position to another.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Every time we remove an element, we have have $(n-1)$ elements left in the list. Can you continue from here?

You say the answer is $(n-1)^2$ , but then you show $10$ good permutations for $n=4$. So , why do you think the answer is $(n-1)^2$?

I only see one duplicate,  (1,2,4,3), which gets us to the claimed $9$.

Sorry, Corrected the question

You probably intended to assume it was a list of distinct elements.

Choose an element to move ($n$ choices).
Choose a new position for that element ($n-1$ choices, since you can't put it back in its original position). HOWEVER,
Each choice where an element moves only one spot gets double counted (for instance if $1$ moves to the right of $2$, you get the same thing as if $2$ moves to the left of $1$). Since there are (originally) $n-1$ neighboring pairs, the above procedure overcounts by $n-1$ configurations.
So the total number of distinct configurations that can be obtained is
$$n\cdot (n-1)-(n-1)=(n-1)^2$$

Alternative approach:
Use induction.
For $~n = 2,~$ the number of satifying permutations is clearly $~1 = (2-1)^2.$
Assume that there are $~(n^2)~$ satisfying permutations, for the elements in $~\{1,2,\cdots,n+1\},~$ and analyze what then happens if the element $~(n+2)~$ is added.
The element $~(n+2)~$ may be left at the end of the list, which implies, by the inductive assumption, that the first term in the computation of the number of satisfying permutations is $~(n^2).~$
Then, the element $~(n+2)~$ may itself be moved into $~(n+1)~$ other positions.  So, the second second term in the computation of the number of satisfying permutations is $~(n+1).~$
Alternatively, one of the other elements might be moved to the end of the list, immediately after the $~(n+2)~$ element.  So, the third term in the computation of the number of satisfying permutations is also $~(n+1).~$
Then, you have to deduct one permutation, because moving the $~(n+1)~$ element to just after the $~(n+2)~$ element is equivalent to moving the $~(n+2)~$ element to just before the $~(n+1)~$ element.  So, using my enumeration method, there is exactly one permutation that is counted twice.  So, the fourth term in the computation of the number of satisfying permutations is $~(-1).~$
So, the enumeration for $~n+2~$ elements is
$$n^2 + (n+1) + (n+1) - 1 = (n+1)^2.$$
So, the assertion is proven by induction.
